# How can I open a new Form from a Thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, thread-safety, asyncsocket

I have an async socket client, and when a packet arrives, I need to handle it by opening a new form.

However, as it is in a thread the new form hangs and does not respond.

How can I create and open a new form from a async callback?

Comment: You need a reference to the app's main form so the async callback can call its BeginInvoke() method and run the code on the UI thread.  You can use Application.OpenForms[0] but that's not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dispatcher, to switch from the background to your UI thread.

```
//This has to be done on the UI-Thread, before calling the async method
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

//Now, in your async callback, do something like this
private void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result){
    dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //Create your form Here           
    }
}
```

If you want your background thread to wait until the Form is created and shown, use Invoke(), else, use Begin

Comment: Dispatcher doesnt exist in my visual studio... Where exactly do you want me to put that?

Comment: Did you add a reference to WindowsBase.dll? Forgot to mention that. You need to get a reference to the dispatcher on the UI thread, so do that anywhere before you invoke anything async. Maybe in a Constructor?